# Returning null values in mysqli query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a mysqli query that calculates how many times a team has scored a certain final score (Total).  I can get this easily enough, but I also want to return the null values.  So basically need to return the below. Currently I don't get the Final Score '13' displaying.

Eg

```
Table : MatchDetails
       Total  | Occurances
        10    | 1
        11    | 3
        12    | 4
        13    | 0
        14    | 3



SELECT Total, COUNT(Total) AS Occurrences
FROM MatchDetails 
WHERE Team = '$Team' GROUP BY Total
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it out.  I created a separate table with the possible final scores in it and left out joined the two tables.

SELECT dataset1.Team, dataset1.Occurrences, s1.FinalScores FROM scoresList s1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Team, COUNT(Total) AS Occurrences, Total 
FROM `MatchDetails` WHERE Team = '$Team' GROUP BY Total) AS dataset1 ON dataset1.Total=s1.FinalScores